# Replacing input method for Android OS

Tags: android, input, event-handling, touch, android-service

I want to replace the touch-based input method of an android device with an alternative one. For example, if the device operates using finger touch, then I want to operate it using a mouse.

I've searched about how to do this for android systems, but all the methods I found controls the input method only in the context of some application. For example, controlling the text input method in some texting application. After reading some tutorials I found that `InputMethodService` can be used to control the input, but I observed that the tutorials use it only in applications, not for the entire OS.

Here are some tutorials I found:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=T3BZWJLQJGRQYMgdgJyXZpK8GPYrcPRLyFw22xQnWxphmXwkz2LJ!-2094516650?v=T000000030

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

But none of them indicates how I can control the input for the entire system. To elaborate more, I want to be able to enable and disable the touch functionality of the entire OS, when it's disabled I want to use my own input method. This input method will be used to control all the applications and settings of the system, just as the touch method is used.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that, or provide me with a useful resource that explains such a process?

Thank you.

Comment: "After reading some tutorials I found that InputMethodService can be used to control the input, but I observed that the tutorials use it only in applications, not for the entire OS" -- no, `InputMethodService` is for the entire device. That's why the user has to go in and manually choose it. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). "I want to be able to enable and disable the touch functionality of the entire OS, when it's disabled I want to use my own input method" -- that would require a custom ROM, not an app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you. So, if I use the IME, will the method that will be selected by the user disable the touch input, or will it work with the touch method?

Comment: An IME does not "disable the touch input". After all, you need "the touch input" to use the IME. An IME is colloquially known as a "soft keyboard". A replacement IME is simply a replacement soft keyboard, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you, but there are some apps available that lock the touch functionality (like this one, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker), do you know how they work?

Comment: Those apps are irrelevant for your stated problem ("replace the touch-based input method of an android device with an alternative one"). If you have questions about how to write such an input blocker, use a search engine (`android block touch input` on Google seems to work well), or ask a separate Stack Overflow question that pertains to that topic.

Comment: Ok I will check for that, thank you.